# gem install append CPPFLAGS / LDFLAGS

Tags: ruby, gem

I can't seem to get `gem install charlock_holmes -v 0.6.9.4` to work.

I can hand edit the `./ext/charlock_holmes/extconf.rb` and includ

```
$INCFLAGS << " -I/usr/local/include "
$LDFLAGS << " -L/usr/local/lib "
```

execute `make` cleanly and re-write the spec file via

```
gem spec ../../cache/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4.gem --ruby > ../../specifications/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4.gemspec
```

and make it a local gem.

1. How do I get the gem to install?
2. There must be a better way to append what amounts to `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` to the gem install.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears the suffix `--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/include` and `--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib` resulting in

```
gem install charlock_holmes -v 0.6.9.4 -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib
```

Accomplishes both 1 & 2 from above.